# Calculating multiple for an input in a stranded time period dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, days

Original table (or Dataframe)

| ID | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-01 | 2021-12-31 |
| 2 | 2019-07-01 | 2021-07-31 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1000 | 2015-01-01 | 2016-03-31 |

Desired table

| ID | Start | End | Start_y | End_y | List | Day for calculation | Days | Multiple |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-01 | 2021-12-31 | 2020 | 2021 | 2020 | 2020-12-31 | 122 | 122/366 |
| 1 | 2020-09-01 | 2021-12-31 | 2020 | 2021 | 2021 | 2021-01-01 | 365 | 122/365 |
| 2 | 2019-07-01 | 2021-07-31 | 2019 | 2021 | 2019 | 2019-12-31 | 184 | 184/365 |
| 2 | 2019-07-01 | 2021-07-31 | 2019 | 2021 | 2020 | 2020-12-31 | 365 | 366/366 |
| 2 | 2019-07-01 | 2021-07-31 | 2019 | 2021 | 2021 | 2021-01-01 | 212 | 212/365 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1000 | 2015-01-01 | 2016-03-31 | 2015 | 2016 | 2015 | 2015-12-31 | 365 | 365/365 |
| 1000 | 2015-01-01 | 2016-03-31 | 2015 | 2016 | 2016 | 2016-01-01 | 91 | 91/365 |

I tried to write as follows until "List" column. But got stuck in calculating days. Any advice on deriving the "Days" column in the desired table?

```
df['Start_y'] = df['Start'].dt.year
df['End_y'] = df['End'].dt.year

def getlist(sta,end):
    return list(range(sta,end+1))

df['List'] = df.apply(lambda x: getlist(x['Start_y'], x['End_y']), axis = 1)
df = df.explode(['List'])
```

Comment: Have you tried subtracting the dates?

Comment: Did. But needed to create a temp dataframe that @Ynjxsjmh did .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
start = pd.to_datetime(df['List'], format='%Y')
end   = start + pd.offsets.YearEnd()

df['Days'] = (pd.concat([end-start, end-df['Start'],
                         df['End']-start, df['End']-df['Start']],
                        axis=1).min(axis=1)
              + pd.Timedelta(days=1))
```

```
print(df)

     ID      Start        End  Start_y  End_y  List     Days
0     1 2020-09-01 2021-12-31     2020   2021  2020 122 days
1     1 2020-09-01 2021-12-31     2020   2021  2021 365 days
2     2 2019-07-01 2021-07-31     2019   2021  2019 184 days
3     2 2019-07-01 2021-07-31     2019   2021  2020 366 days # 2020 is leap year
4     2 2019-07-01 2021-07-31     2019   2021  2021 212 days
5  1000 2015-01-01 2016-03-31     2015   2016  2015 365 days
6  1000 2015-01-01 2016-03-31     2015   2016  2016  91 days
```